# How to add URL hyperlink to nodes created in network graphs with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, igraph

I have successfully created a 3D network graph using Plotly and igraph in python using this helpful [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-interactive-3d-network-with-python-plotly-4ef6989d83cc).

I want to manipulate those nodes meaning adding a hyperlink to each node so when I click on the nodes it should open that URL.
Does anyone have any idea if it's possible with plotly? If not any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.